# I want to be able to import the JavaMail API and use it in Android Studio. What do I do after downloading mail.jar and activation.jar?

Tags: email, android-studio, jakarta-mail

I have created a classpath variable and set it to

C:\Program Files\Java\javax.mail.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jaf-1.1.1\activation.jar

I still can't import javax.mail. What else I do need to do? I am running Windows 8.1

Comment: Note that there is now a special version of [JavaMail for Android](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Android).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After downloading mail.jar, activation.jar and additional.jar, copy and paste these 3 jars into the libs folder of the android studio project. To access the libs folder of a project in Android Studio, change from Android view to Project view and you will see the libs folder above src. Then, right click on each jar and Add to Library. Click "Ok" for each, and you will be set. All that is left to do is the import javax.mail in your java code.